# Default credentials for hue in hortonworks sandbox

Tags: hue

I'm using Hortonworks sandbox. I cannot login to the hue using port 8000 since I don't know the password. Can some one tell me the default password and username for hue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've faced the same problem regarding users on hue platform. As this link says http://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.3.4/bk_installing_manually_book/content/configure_hue.html:

> By default, the first user who logs in to Hue can choose any username
>   and password and gets the administrator privileges. This user can
>   create other user and administrator accounts. User information is
>   stored in the Django database in the Django backend

So for user management, you have to interact with Django backend. Changing the password for user hue can be done with the following steps:

1. login to hortonwork sandbox
2. go to **/usr/lib/hue** (base directory for hue platform)
3. execute **build/env/bin/hue shell** within that directory (that will enter you in the python console)
4. Execute the following python code:

   ```
   from django.contrib.auth.models import User
   user = User.objects.get(username='hue')
   user.set_password('admin')
   user.save()
   ```

That will change your hue's password to admin. More information can be found in this link http://gethue.com/password-management-in-hue/

Answer (score 0):

Go to the Hortonworks sandbox homepage using the ipaddress and click on the 'close Advanced Options'.  You will find all the default credentials there.